# Prove that if $A=BQ$ then $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm having some trouble with a question in my linear algebra textbook:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite matrices, and let $Q$ be a unitary matrix.
>   Prove that if $A=BQ$, then $A=B$.

I tried to play around with the given equality, but I'm not getting any results. Tips would be appreciated:)

Comment: yes you're right, i only noticed it after i posted

Comment: Contrary to the approach given in that answer, it suffices to note that positive definite matrices have unique positive definite square roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A = BQ$, then 
$AA^* = BQ(BQ)^*$.